# XAMPP deny access from specific external IP address

Tags: proxy, virtualhost, .htaccess, proxypass, xampp

I need some help with securing my test XAMPP server as so far nothing I have tried seems to work.
I am running Apache 2.4.7 on Windows 7 machine.

The setup is the following:

I am redirecting all traffic coming on my server IP, port 80 to a java application running on `localhost:5000`.

The code doing all this in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName demo.website.com
  ServerAlias website.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
  <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
  </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

The question is, how do I `deny` traffic from specific external IP address?

It seems I cannot use `.htaccess` because requests on port 80 are redirected to a java application, not a xampp folder containing web content.

Also, the code below does not do the job either:

```
<Proxy *>
    order allow,deny
    deny from 193.37.XXX.XX
    allow from all
</Proxy>
```

What other options are there?

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

After the responses I got, it looks I have been doing the proxy reverse entirely wrong opening exploitable gaps in the server. Based on the answer provided, I have modified my initial code.

Since I am using similar insecure code for port 443 and I cannot get apache to start after the new modifications, I have posted a new question [HERE](https://serverfault.com/questions/984662/xampp-how-to-secure-forward-proxy-for-port-443).

Comment: You should remove the entire `<Proxy>` section from you configuration entirely. Do not put this in your configuration, no matter what else you read on the Internet. It configures a _forward_ proxy and in this case opens your server to abuse, and it is not necessary to configure a _reverse_ proxy, which is what you want.

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your answer! I understand what you are saying and I had the same concerns as well. How do you suggest that I handle this - I do need to have the traffic coming on my external IP address to the localhost port 5000?

Comment: Your edit would really be a new question since it is a different problem. Generally, when Apache can't start you can find the reason for it in the log files.

Comment: A blind guess would be that the module `mod_proxy_wstunnel` is not loaded.

Comment: Thank you Gerald, I will set the EDIT as new question. The `mod_proxy_wstunnel` is enabled and the old and insecure code works just fine. The issue is with the vhosts file, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @MichaelHampton already commented: **remove the following settings immediately:**

```
<Proxy *>
    order allow,deny
    deny from 193.37.XXX.XX
    allow from all
</Proxy>
```

Those are not needed for a *reverse proxy* but instead used to configure a ***forward*** proxy , open to almost anybody, which will allow your server to be abused. ( Fortunately you still also used [`ProxyRequests off`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests) )

BTW  when you do need a forward proxy, please don't use Apache httpd but a more specific product.

---

> It seems I cannot use .htaccess ...

IMHO You're already heading the wrong direction with your intention to create a `.htaccess` files, which is  my pet peeve, quoted from from the [manual on .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#when) files:

> You should **avoid using `.htaccess` files completely** *if you have access to httpd main server config* file. Using **`.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server**. Any directive that you can include in a `.htaccess` file is better set in a [`Directory`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) block in the main Apache configuration file(s), as it will have the same effect with better performance) and combine that with

But the reason that in this case a .htaccess won't work is that they apply settings to a resources on the local file system, from a directory, and with a reverse proxy the content is retrieved from elsewhere by Apache httpd.

---

The solution to your actual problem, as how to apply additional access controls and IP-addresss white/blacklisting on a reverse proxy URL: You place the `ProxyPass` directives and additional directives in a `<Location>` block in your configuration (which also [since Apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/new_features_2_4.html#module) happens to be the configuration syntax that offers the best performance) and add to the IP-address restriction with a [`Require`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) directive to that location:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ServerName demo.website.com
  ServerAlias website.com

  <Location />
    <RequireAll>
      # Block IP-addresses from the 193.37.0.0/16 and 10.9.8.0/24 networks 
      Require not ip 193.37 10.9.8
      # Allow all other IP's
      Require all granted
    </RequireAll> 
    ProxyPass http://localhost:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5000/
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: HBruijn, thank you for the time taken to explain everything in detail, I do appreciate your effort! I tried modifying my vhosts file as you suggest but I get Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly error. Apache starts fine after I remove `Require not ip 193.37 10.9.8`. Any idea why this happens? Also, I edited the initial question to reflect the virtual host configuration for port 443, may I ask you to have a look? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you typically get more of an error in the log files indicating what the problem is, does apachectl configtest return a valid config?

Comment: Ah I see what the problem is, comments in apache are on a line of their own and when you copy [my original sample config](https://serverfault.com/revisions/984646/1) verbatim with the `Require settings #comment`  it breaks, edited accordingly

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I removed the comments but apache still didn't start. So running `apachectl configtest` I get this: `negative Require directive has no effect in <RequireAny> directive`

Comment: Your last edit works! Thank you for the support! May I ask you to check my second question under EDIT? I have similar problems for port 443. Again I really appreciate the time you take to help me with this!